# tabbed navigation is too nested

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, lean-ux

I do not like the nested 'tabs' although my requirment is to put the 3 tabs in the administration tab as it belongs there. I have also thought about a vertical *schoolclasses/weightedtests/weightedsubjects* tab button bar, but that would take away too much space which I need horizontally.

Does someone know a user friendly layout or component so I can better display this nested *schoolclasses/weightedtests/weightedsubjects* level? Because architecturally it is right to have those elements nested. I just would like to have it more flat/rearranged. Or is it just me that I think thats a nogo?

[image]

Comment: Elements inside reporting, for example, are not again schoolclasses/... , weighted tests, weighted subjects, right?

Comment: Right. Inside reporting are other things like 2 charts about grades/marks also each chart in its own tab.

Comment: you should go for the solution given by @J. Dimeo. I am also suggesting you the same

Comment: yes I liked his suggestion most as the display is very natural to my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a hierarchical or tree organization instead along the left side?
[image: Tree example]

In your case, the top level elements would be "Admin", "Tests" and "Reporting".

Comment: Hm.. hm... yes I like it! This would be on the left side then. Why did I not think of that :P That way I embrace the hierarchical architectur of a component tree, what makes the impl. very easy and grateful!

Comment: Great! glad it was helpful. That screenshot was from a UI that I just switched to that layout myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the complexity by selecting the project in a different page (you can still put it inside a dropdown in the image below); including the second level under a different element such as a dropdown; the buttons as you have them right now look the same as tabs so give them a different styling; hide the editable section behind an Edit button.

[image]

Comment: how do you choose and then open a project? This is very unusual actually to put the tabs into a dropdown. Or is this just me? I use angular2 which is component orientend and putting the children(admin/tests/reporting) on the same ui level as project is what I wanted avoid as it needs technically seen much effort and I have already been there...